# Redirect non www URL to www URL using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I want to redirect all non-www requests to my domain (e.g. http://domainname.com to http://www.domainname.com).

I know I can use [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) but I wanted to know if there's an inbuilt way of doing it in Spring MVC?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

A Spring MVC based application can only access application root and can handle URLs after root e.g /myapp, /myapp/dashboard etc

To update domain name within the request you must configure using Servlet API (filters) or use Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter as you mentioned.

I would advice you to do this server level. If you using Apache as your primary http server then redirection can be done using .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^viralpatel\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.viralpatel.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above rule redirects viralpatel.net to wwww.viralpatel.net

Reference: [.htaccess tips/tricks](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/21-very-useful-htaccess-tips-tricks/)

Comment: Hi Viral, I used Tuckey to do this:
My urlrewrite.xml looks like:

        <rule>
      <name>Domain Name Check</name>
      <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.mydomain.com</condition>
      <from>^(.*)</from>
      <to type="redirect">http://www.mydomain.com$1</to>
     </rule>

This seem to work perfectly.
Any changes suggested in the regex?

Comment: Your urlrewrite mapping looks correct. What application server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for validating.I'm using Tomcat as my server. I don't have separate Web and Application servers.